# I can't get match string with regex in nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js, exec

I have a string like below

```
let value : '<ns2:NewsPaper unitid="112345">
        <idType>DG</idType>
      </ns2:NewsPaper>'
```

I need content of 
`<ns2:NewsPaper.` I write a piece of code. But it returns null. Here is my code :

```
let abc = /NewsPaper>(\*)</.exec(value);
        console.log(abc);
```

It returns null. Why?

Comment: Why do you try to match `>` after `NewsPaper` if the input string has no `>` after it? The string has no `*`, why use `\*` in the pattern then? Use `/NewsPaper\b[^<]*\bunitid="([^"]+)"/` and use `.exec(value)[1]`.

Comment: This is a nitpick, but you shouldn't need to use `var` and `let` like this. I presume you're using them interchangeably. I'd be more deliberate with my use of `var`, `let`, and `const`. Frankly, if you're using a version of `node` that supports ES6, then you should just use `let` and `const` and avoid using `var`.

Comment: Also `var value = "<ns2:NewsPaper unitid="112234">";` isn't valid JS. You'll need to escape the internal double-quotes like this `\"` or wrap the assignment in single quotes like this `var value = '<ns2:NewsPaper ...`

Comment: This is still not valid JS. You cannot initialize a variable with `let x : <value>`. Also JS supports multiline strings, but not in the way that you're using them. Use ES6's template strings for this.

Answer (score 0):

A easier way to match will be:

```
let rex = /unitid=\"\d*\"/g;
let abc = rex.exec(value); // ["unitid="112234"", "unitid="112234""]
```

Comment: I want to newPaper's contents

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for what you're scraping:

```
unitid="[^"]+"
```

It will match `unitid="` literally, character for character. Then it will match `[^"]`

As for the JS like this:

```
const value = '<ns2:NewsPaper unitid="112234">';
const regex = /unitid="[^"]+?"/;
const matches = value.match(regex);

console.log(matches);
// => ["unitid=\"112234\""]
```

Notice how the capturing parens aren't necessary. This is because of JS's implementation of the `match(..)` function. Your output when you include capturing parens will be:

```
["unitid=\"112234\"", "unitid=\"112234\""]
```

You should expect this same behavior even if you use the `exec(..)` function. So in certain cases like this, omitting the capturing parens can be desirable. The first element of the `matches` array will be whatever your regex consumed; everything that follows this first element will be the items that your regex captured.

[Here's a link to the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/mejaja/edit?js,console).

Comment: I want newsPaper's content . HOw ?

Comment: I think this should have been more clear in the original question.

Comment: can you have an idea

Comment: You should use an XML scraper for this. Regexes can work, but an XML scraper is a better tool for the job. Also, what do you mean by "content"? Remaining attributes of the opening tag? Or the children nested within that tag? Your question should be more clear.

Comment: remaining attributes of the opening tag.

Comment: Use this regex: `<ns2:NewsPaper([^>]+)>`